# Speeding up pycontractions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, word2vec

I'm using a function from [pycontractions](https://github.com/ian-beaver/pycontractions/blob/master/README.rst) to try to expand text into its grammatically accurate form. It works but its incredibly slow and I cannot help but wonder if I am doing something unnecessary that is contributing to the lag in performance. For reference, it is taking close to a minute to output.

```
from pycontractions import Contractions

def cont_expand(a):
    cont = Contractions(api_key="glove-twitter-100")
    expText = cont.expand_texts(a, precise=False)

return expText

mystr = ["I'd like to have lunch today"]
x = list(cont_expand(mystr))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't previously known about or worked with the `pycontractions` library, but from a quick look, I have a few ideas.

First and foremost, regarding your usage:

The `Contractions` object needs to load-from-disk a large set of pre-existing word-vectors to do some of its analysis. It also needs to instantiate another library `language-check` which apparently wraps on a Java-based grammar-checking utility.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ian-beaver/pycontractions/blob/6023c637956a5fa1e2cf8714aa53e10cfb807305/pycontractions/contractions.py#L390), I see that it actually does these initializations in a lazy fashion when first needed during `expand_texts()`, rather than during the object initialization when `api_key='glove-twitter-100'` was provided.)

On a small text like your probe value, that *might* be the largest contributor to runtime. So, a single `expand_texts()` on a just-initialized `Contractions` object won't be an accurate indicator of that object's performance on following similar texts. So, assuming your real usage will be on more than one text per Python-invocation, you should:

- change your code to re-use a single, once-instantiated `Contractions` object
- force that object to fully-load its subcomponents, taking that hit up-front, before benchmarking it on real work

For example:

```
from pycontractions import Contractions

PYCNTRCTNS = Contractions(api_key="glove-twitter-100")

# dummy call to force vector/grammar loading
PYCNTRCTNS.expand_texts([])  # expect this to take a while

def cont_expand(a):
    expText = PYCNTRCTNS.expand_texts(a, precise=False)
    return expText

mystr = ["I'd like to have lunch today"]
x = list(cont_expand(mystr))  # care about how long this takes
```

Other than that, your usage is pretty simple, and I don't see other things you can do, by calling that library differently, to speed things up.

However, looking a little into how `pycontractions` works, I wouldn't be surprised that it's fairly slow, especially on large texts. The things it's doing, internally, are often fairly-slow processes, and it's additionally doing them in ways that aren't heavily optimized – which may be perfectly fine, for simplicity of code, and especially on short texts, unless/until higher performance is needed.

For example, it describes using a "three-pass" approach.

- The first pass involves a number of pattern-based replacements, for which the source code has **hundreds** of individual regular-expressions. Every text needs to be regular-expression-matched across these hundreds of expressions, in a loop, to perform this 1st step. (There are ways to optimize this to use fewer passes.)
- For contractions that have multiple possible expansions – which includes the "I'd" in your test string – it performs each expansion & checks its grammar. Fortunately, this only involves a few expansions, but grammar-checking isn't the cheapest of operations, either.
- For every alternate expansion, it calculates a word-vector-based semantic-difference measure called "Word Mover's Distance" from the original text, that itself can be quite expensive, especially on longer texts. (It's doing this from scratch for each alternate – even though except for a couple words, each alternate starts identical – and even after it's found at least one grammatical option, it continues doing this calculation for non-grammatical candidates that have no chance of being chosen.)

And at each step, it's keeping interim results as raw strings, so either `pycontractions` code or the individual supporting libraries' code is repeatedly performing the same tokenization steps.

So: if you were doing this in bulk, and fixes to the underlying library were in scope, there's likely a lot of room for micro-optimizations.

But I think for many casual uses, just being sure you aren't repeatedly paying the `Contractions` initialization-loading cost on each operations may be enough of an improvement.